# Can you partition a floppy disk?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, floppy

I read somewhere that floppy disks cannot be partitioned with most modern computer software tools. However, can't a floppy disk simply be viewed as an array of bytes like other magnetic storage devices? What prevents you from creating a boot sector and implementing some kind of partition map (e.g. MBR) like you can with a hard disk?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You certainly can partition a floppy. Nothing prevents you from doing it, and it should work just fine on Linux when you mount it.

But given the small amount of data you can store on a floppy, having several partitions doesn't make sense, so it's just a waste of space. That's why nobody is doing it.

Also, most tools (and old OS like DOS) will be confused by a partition table, and won't work correctly any more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any idea why the Wikipedia page for volumes in computing says that "A volume is not the same thing as a partition. For example, a floppy disk might be accessible as a volume, even though it does not contain a partition, as floppy disks cannot be partitioned with most modern computer software"

Comment: I'd suggest you make a new question for that. Yes, the concept of a "volume"  is different from a partition. For example, a volume may span multiple partitions; or you may have a volume on a device that's not partitioned, like a floppy. "Floppy disks cannot be partitioned with most modern computer software" may be actually true, depending on your definition of "most" (which is probably Windows-related, and they may have a check in there to prevent it. Just because it's Microsoft, and they want to prevent the stupid users from doing things). Try with `fdisk` on Linux...

Comment: @MatthewInbox  Think of a "Volume" as anything that can have a filesystem on it. Usually that is a partition, but you can put a filesystem directly on the raw disk. (That is the normal situation for floppies.)

Comment: This won't work on Linux. Well, actually partitioning will work, but the kernel won't accept this as a partition table. I've just tried `fdisk`'ing it, and _"Calling `ioctl()` to re-read partition table"_ gave me _"WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 22: Invalid argument"_, and `/dev/fd?*` only lists `/dev/fd0`. You may be more successful with `losetup` and then mounting the loop devices you map the partitions to, but that's just simulation, not "working just fine".

Comment: @Rusian: I said "`fdisk` is working just fine" and "if you can mount it". I didn't say "partitioning will work out of the box" (though it should be possible to make that work with a bit of fiddling). And yes, giving offset and lenght for mounting is the simplest way.